# Django Biginner - How to connect my algorithm code in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This might be simple, but I'm quite new to django. I want to build app to make the user upload a csv file, run my algorithm on it, and then make the output file available to be downloaded by the user. I already started my uploading file thing and it looks like it's working, and I already have my algorithm code ready, however, I'm not sure how to connect my algorithm code, also not sure how to make another function to include that, and do I need a new url for each uploading,running the algorithm and downloading? what I would like is one URL that displays the three of them. Here is my project files and app, the `model.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Upload(models.Model):
    pic = models.FileField("CSV File", upload_to="images/")
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)

# FileUpload form class.
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = '__all__'  # Or a list of the fields that you want to include in your form
```

**`View.py:`**

```
from __future__ import division
from django.shortcuts import render
from uploader.models import UploadForm,Upload
from io import TextIOWrapper
from io import StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import csv
import logging
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if img.is_valid():
            img.save()
          #  request.FILES['pic'].open("f")
          #  portfolio = csv.DictReader(request.FILES['uploadFile'].file)

           #file =request.FILES['pic']
            file1 = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['pic'].file)
           # reader = StringIO(file.read().decode())
            reader = file1.read()
            file1.seek(0)
            portfolio = csv.DictReader(reader)
            print(portfolio)
            #with open(reader) as f:
            my_list=[]
            import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
          #  with open(portfolio) as f:
            my_list = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in portfolio]
          #  for row in portfolio:
             #   my_list = [row["BASE_NAME"]]
              #
            print(my_list)
            logging.warning('Watch out!')  # will print a message to the console

         #   for row in reader:
         #       print (row)
        #else:
         #   print (img.errors)
         #   print  (request.FILES)
           # img.save()
            #file = request.FILES[pic]
           # with open(file) as f:
               # my_list = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in DictReader(f)]

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

My `home.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>Upload the CSV File</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    {% for img in images %}
        {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ img.pic.url }}">{{ img.pic.name }}</a>
        ({{img.upload_date}})<hr />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my `url.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/$', 'uploader.views.home', name='imageupload'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`My algorithm code` I want to implement is:

```
with open("export.csv") as f:
    my_list = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in DictReader(f)]
# CodeCSvModel.import_from_file(file)
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
k = len(my_list)
dist1 = np.subtract(np.ones((k, k), dtype=np.float), similarity)
data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))

no_clus = 1500
for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
    km = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=no_clus, linkage='average').fit(arr_3d[i])

    labels = km.labels_

csvfile = file
csv_input = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
csv_input.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
clus_groups = list()
for j in range(no_clus):
    list_of_ints = ([my_list[i] for i, x in enumerate(labels) if x == j])
    clus_groups.append('  '.join(list_of_ints))
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

lsa = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
k = len(my_list)
dist1 = 1 - similarity
data2 = np.asarray(dist1)
arr_3d = data2.reshape((1, k, k))

no_clus = 5
for i in range(len(arr_3d)):
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++')
    km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])
    labels2 = km.labels_

labels = labels.tolist()
labels2 = labels2.tolist()

csv_input = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
labels1 = csv_input['cluster_ID']
new_list = []
for k in labels1:
    new_list.append(labels2[k])  # lookup the value in list2 at the index given by list1
csv_input = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
csv_input['cluster_ID'] = labels
csv_input['BASE_NAME'] = my_list
csv_input['User_Map'] = new_list
csv_input.to_csv('output1.csv', index=False)
```

I already tried in my view.py to make `my_list` and to start, however not sure if I got my_list right since no print statements are showing, I also want to make a function inside the view to implement my algorithm above, and how to link the file I got from `home` function with the new function of the algorithm, I will also need another function for the downloading thing, and not sure about the templates. I'm kinda lost and did the uploading function by an example online. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you taken the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)? That explains pretty thoroughly how to modify your models and views, how to work with the templating system, etc.

Comment: Yes I did, and searched and read alot of examples. I'm still litt confused about connecting my own code which is not explained in the tutorials, also having troubled with connecting urls and writing templates

Comment: Are you absolutely certain nothing is printing? I just ran your code, and upon clicking on the upload button when a file has been selected, it prints the instance of the class

Comment: @bitterman, yeah I saw that, how can I convert the first column of the uploaded file into a list?